# Can i merge/combine graphql API arrays into one?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, graphql, gatsby, sanity

Hey i'm using Sanity and have created both a allSanityPost (for my blog posts) and allSanityCases (for all my cases). Do anyone know how to combine these categories into one array and order them by their "published-date"? I want to display them both on one blog page - but not in separated lists.

I'm building the page with Gatsby, so react answers would be preferable :)

Cheers

Comment: Is your goal to merge the queries or just the results of two queries?

Answer (score 0):

The current GraphQL endpoint have no way of querying across documents like GROQ does. Therefore, you will have to do this after querying the GraphQL endpoint for data. I suggest querying for both all posts and all cases separately like this:

```
query {
  allSanityPost{
    title
  },
  allSanityCases{
    title
  }
}
```

Given that both of these types have some sort of date, you should be able to  combine them into one single array, and then do your sorting thereafter.